# “Cannot read property 'id' of undefined” error

Tags: node.js, reactjs

```js
export const isAuthenticated = () =>

 { if (typeof window == 'undefined') {

 return false; }

 if (localStorage.getItem('jwt')) {

 return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('jwt')); } 

else { return false; } 
};
```

[image: screenshot]

I'm using react js for frontend and node js for backend.Is this error about the backend?

Comment: To answer to your question it's necessary to have a bit of code to reproduce your context and work and your question.

Comment: 1) Please post errors and code as text instead of an off-site screenshot. It makes it easier for people to help. 2) `user` is undefined, but its impossible to tell where the error is with the limited code provided. `isAuthenticated` sounds like it should return a boolean, but I can't say for sure.

Comment: Can you please post how `isAuthenticated()` function looks like as text?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Looks like ```isAuthenticated``` doesn't return ```user``` object

Comment: `export const isAuthenticated = () => {
   
    if (typeof window == 'undefined') {
        return false;
    }

    if (localStorage.getItem('jwt')) {
        return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('jwt'));
    } else {
        return false;
    }
};`

Comment: Byt the way I can see the jwt token for the user when I clicked in application in the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because it is not able to find `_id` in the `user` object. So you can do this to make sure there is already `user` object

```
<Link
      to={`users/${isAuthenticated().user && isAuthenticated().user._id}`}
    >
```

Comment: I can see the jwt token on the console so I think there is a user tho

Answer (score -1):

Why are you calling isAuthenticated().user._id, from what I can see in your code, isAuthenticated() is returning the token not the user and jwt tokens do not contain an _id property.

I think what you are trying to do or what you should do is to get the token, then decode it and get the payload, your user object which contains the _id property is probably found there.

You can decode the token using the jwt-decode package

```js
export const isAuthenticated = () =>

 { if (typeof window == 'undefined') {

 return false; }

 if (localStorage.getItem('jwt')) {

 const token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('jwt')); 
 
   const decoded: any = decode(token);
   return decoded.user._id
 }


else { return false; } 
};
```

Comment: Do u think it's the reason why my application is too slow or is it just about the mongodb atlas

Comment: I suggest you include a code snippet with your answer.